# Request user location without nodejs library

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I was successfully able to request user location with help of action-on-google nodejs library, but I am more of java guy, and I need to do this in java.

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#json

[How can I request the user's location in API.ai?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389874/how-can-i-request-the-users-location-in-api-ai)

[Requesting User Location from Google Actions with Api.ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043499/requesting-user-location-from-google-actions-with-api-ai)

From above links, I find out that it is possible with just json reponses.

I've created my poc app in api.ai, which returns below json reponses

## 1

```
{
    "conversationToken": {
        "state": null,
        "data": {}
    },
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [
        {
            "inputPrompt": {
                "initialPrompts": [
                    {
                        "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
                    }
                ],
                "noInputPrompts": null
            },
            "possibleIntents": [
                {
                    "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
                    "inputValueData": {
                        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                        "optContext": "Requesting Location.",
                        "permissions": [
                            "DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This returns : 
[Unparseable Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPnct.png)

## 2

```
{
    "contextOut": [
        {
            "lifespan": 100,
            "name": "_actions_on_google_",
            "parameters": null
        },
        {
            "lifespan": 5,
            "name": "requesting_permission",
            "parameters": null
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "google": {
            "expect_user_response": true,
            "is_ssml": false,
            "no_input_prompts": null,
            "permissions_request": {
                "opt_context": "Requesting Location.",
                "permissions": [
                    "DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "speech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION"
}
```

This return :
[PLACEHOLDER TEXT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XRwb.png)

I wanted to know that way I am doing it is possible or not. If yes, what I am doing wrong ?

Please help.

Comment: Now there is an unofficial Java/Kotlin SDK.  It has all the features of the nodejs and very similar api.  I maintain the project and will be updating docs and readme soon, but it is ready for use and is on maven central. https://github.com/TicketmasterMobileStudio/actions-on-google-kotlin

Comment: @Patrick thanks, I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters - yes, this is possible. You can use JSON to request the permission. All the node.js libraries do is help format the JSON.

Most of this looks correct, but I think there are two different types of errors here.

The first is that I suspect there are a few fields that are causing problems at API.AI/Google in your first example. The two fields that are null, `conversationToken.state` and `expectedInputs.inputPrompt.noInputPrompts`, are likely causing problems. The `state` field should just be a string (any string is fine) and the `noInputPrompts` should be an empty array.

Furthermore, you indicate that you're using API.AI, which requires additional information to be sent back and most of what you've indicated to be in a `data.google` section (which you have in your second example, but not your first). See https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#response for the base layout of an API.AI response and https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/webhook#response for the additional fields used by the Google Assistant.

Here is some output that I generated that works:

```
{
    "speech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_PERMISSION",
    "contextOut": [
        {
            "name": "_actions_on_google_",
            "lifespan": 100,
            "parameters": {}
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "isSsml": false,
            "noInputPrompts": [],
            "systemIntent": {
                "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
                "data": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                    "optContext": "To pick you up",
                    "permissions": [
                        "NAME",
                        "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It work as I wanted. :)

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, I have a question : Once we get user name and location permission, is there any way we can store the permission for that session only and whenever it's required, I just get it, is it possible ?

Comment: For additional/different questions, it is best if you ask another SO question rather than try to use comments to followup. In this case, however, it has already been asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044623/google-assistant-location-permissions-not-stored-between-requests If that answers your question, upvote the question and answer. If not - ask a new question with as much info as you can.